# Why does this “proof” for the Collatz conjecture not work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, fake-proofs, collatz-conjecture

After seeing a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=094y1Z2wpJg) on the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), I kind of played around with it a bit and found the following result (which can be shown by induction):

$$\underbrace{f \circ \ldots \circ f}_{N \text{ times}}(2^N x - 1) = 6^{\left\lceil\frac{N}{2}\right\rceil} x - 2 + (N + 1) \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} 2.$$

If the Collatz conjecture were true, then $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} : \lim_\limits{N \to \infty} \underbrace{f \circ \ldots \circ f}_{N \text{ times}}(x) = 1$. However, the result above would imply that for any number of function applications, $N$, there is an (infinite set of) input(s) that will be larger than the inputs and therefore can not be one. So, even if $N \to \infty$ there will be inputs (of the form $2^N x - 1$) that do not go to 1.

Since much smarter people have worked on this, this “proof” is probably not sound, but I was wondering where the problem(s) lies exactly.

One possible caveat is that this idea breaks if it would be possible to apply the function uncountably many times (which would be rather counterintuitive to me).

I would appreciate any insights as to where this line of reasoning fails

Comment: Is the number of applications of $f$ the same $N$ as the exponent of $2$?

Comment: I haven’t checked your math, but your reasoning is wrong. For each $N$ you claim there are (infinitely many) inputs that haven’t converged *yet* after $N$ iterations. So what? Each of these inputs still have plenty of time to converge — they don’t need to follow each other. What you might be able to conclude is that $f$ don’t converge *uniformly*.

Comment: @Arthur the number of applications of $f$ is the same as the exponent of 2

Comment: @Milten Exactly. It’s just that if you take another $N$ iterations, there will be inputs (e.g. $4^N x - 1$) that will become even larger. So, no matter how often you add iterations, there will always be an input that does not converge to one, no matter how often you repeat the function. I am probably misunderstanding infinity in some way…

Comment: @MrTsjolder Consider the simpler function $f(x) = \max(x-1, 0)$ for $x\in\Bbb N_0$. Clearly this converges to $0$ for all inputs. But after any given number of iterations $N$, there are still infinitely many inputs that haven't converged, namely all $x>N$. Do you see the similarity? And why we clearly can't conclude that $f$ doesn't converge when iterated?

Comment: @Milten that’s exactly what I needed, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that by increasing the number of iterations and, most crucially, **also increase the starting point**, you can reach arbitrarily large numbers with the Collatz procedure.

The Collatz conjecture concerns whether somewhere out there, there is a **single** starting point which never comes down to 1 (either by looping, or by getting large) as you increase the number of iterations. You have not addressed this in your proof.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side of your result is independent of $x$. More precisely, it is $\equiv N+1 \mod 2$. This would mean that for fixed $N$, all odd numbers of the form $2^{N}x - 1$ have the same $N$-th Collatz iteration, which is false.

BTW: On your result,  it is not clear why the power of $2$ on the left-hand side should be equal to $N$.

Comment: the power of 2 is $N$ by design: it is an input that will always be larger.